# What is the significance of using prime numbers in proving: $x$ is a multiply of $y$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, prime-numbers

**I came to a problem where it asks me to prove, for example, $n^4-n^2$ is a multiple of $12$.**

Now, factorize the multiple: $n\times n\times (n-1)\times (n+1)$. Here we have $3$ consecutive integers. Any three consecutive integers say something that one of them must be a multiple of $3$. Likewise for $2$ in any $2$ consecutive integers . Here I cannot say any thing about $6$ or $4$ because we do not have $4$ consecutive integers nor $6$ although $12$ can be written as $6\times 2$ or $3\times 4$.

But, assume that we have $4$ consecutive  integers in some how, I "heard" that you cannot prove that the product of these $4$ is divisible by $4$ but you can use $2$ since it is a *prime*.

Why $2$ and not $4$? **Why to use a prime and not a non *prime*?**

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even then it's divisible by $4$ because it's divisible by $n^2$.  Now if $n$ is odd then you have two even terms $n-1$ and $n+1$ so it's still divisible by $4$

Comment: Are you referring to the n^4-n^2 multiple?

Comment: Yes after you factor as $n^2(n-1)(n+1)$ you see it's divisible both by $n^2$ and by $(n-1)(n-2)$.  If $n$ is even the first one is divisible by $4$ and if $n$ is odd the second one is divisible by $4$.  So in either case $n^4-n^2$ must be divisible by $4$.

Comment: You don't mean $(n-1)(n-2)$, you mean $(n-1)(n+1)$.

Comment: But you did not answer my question then. I am asking why to use 3 and 2, which are primes, and not 4 (consider it is divisible by 4 now after you showed me).

Comment: I don't actually think they're looking for anything more significant regarding primes than the argument I've given.  The point is that there are two terms  in the factorization that are divisible by $2$ and not necessarily any divisible by $4$.  That's what's important about the number $2$ here and not the fact that it's a prime in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You can still rewrite it to make use of what you want: the product of $4$ consecutive integers is divisible by $4! = 24$, and the product of $3$ consecutive integers is divisible by $3! = 6$. We have: $n^4 - n^2 = n\times n\times (n-1)\times (n+1) = (n-1)\times n\times (n+1)\times ((n+2) - 2)= (n-1)\times n\times (n+1)\times (n+2) - 2\times (n-1)\times n\times (n+1)$. This expression is divisible by $12$ since its the difference of two integers that is each divisible by $12$.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no significance of using prime numbers in this "proving" issue?

Comment: Right. I think you intend to use the property of "coprime" or relatively prime integers rather than "solid" prime. You see that $(3,4) = 1$ and these are coprime numbers and $4$ is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

Why will you take $4$?

Look at $n\cdot n\cdot(n-1)(n+1)$.

Assume $n$ to be $2$.Then the factors become $2,2,1,3$.You don't have $4$ anywhere.But,you can break $4$ into $2\cdot 2$.So you see the two $2$'s will always cancel.So you may now realize that we are doing all works using the smallest constituent prime factors.

In general all composite numbers can be expressed as prime factors (by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic).So,its same to show that a number $p$ has a factor which is a composite number $z$ by showing that all prime factors $z$ are factors of $p$

Comment: But here is a point: can you show that n*n*(n-1)*(n+1) is divisible by 3 and 4(not 3 and 2) at the same time? The issue may be in this: that 4 will eat the whole factors and there is nothing left for 3?

Comment: nvm for my last comment. It is one of the three consecutive integers is divisible by 3 so it would not contradict that the others can be divisible by 4.

Comment: @Gold_Sky Yeah it can be proved simultaneously for $3$ and $4$...there's no contradiction....